# What do the identifiers mean on the /reputation page?

Tags: support, reputation

All users have [their own page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation) where they can see all the reputation changes, per day, per question. There is one page per community you're part of, with addresses such as (basically the site address, ending in `/reputation`:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation
https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
```

There are identifiers in the beginning of each line (except the daily summary lines). These represent the following potential reputation changes:

```
1 : Accept (+2 if you accept, +15 if your answer is accepted)
2 : Upvote (+5 for question, +10 for answer)
3 : Downvote (-1 if you downvote an answer, -2 if you get downvoted)
8 : Give bounty
9 : Receive bounty
16: Approved edit (+2)
```

I'm wondering what the missing numbers `4-7`, and `10-15` represent, and if they exist at all.

My research indicates that (it might be incorrect, but I think it's right):

- Reputation changes due to deleted users are not part of the list. (The vote disappears from the day you got it, it's not shown as a `+/-` change on the day the user got deleted.
- Serial-voting reversal is not part of the list. (The vote disappears from the day you got it, it's not shown as a `+/-` change on the day the votes got reversed.
- Un-upvote / un-downvote are not part of the list. (The vote disappears from the day you got it, it's not shown as a `+/-` change on the day it was changed.

The Association bonus is shown on the second line, without an identifier, so that's not part of the list either.

So, what are the remaining ones, and do they exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the same values as in the [VoteTypes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/664845/votetypes) table available from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

```
1 AcceptedByOriginator
2 UpMod
3 DownMod
4 Offensive
5 Favorite
6 Close
7 Reopen
8 BountyStart
9 BountyClose
10 Deletion
11 Undeletion
12 Spam
15 ModeratorReview
16 ApproveEditSuggestion
```

So there are some undocumented or missing numbers (13 & 14) but fewer than you imagine. Some such as favorite and close don't result in a rep change so won't appear in the reputation link.

Reversals and deletion are as you say, basically it's as if the votes never existed in the first place.